# dropDownList doesn't load fast enough when using fadeIn on it the first time

Tags: jquery, css, performance

in this 
[sample](http://responsivepx.com/?https%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io%2F7asobate%2Fpen%2FbpjVmd#520x1606)

I have a simble dropdownList .. it's hidden by

> display:none

I used the following code to fadeIn the navbar whenever the user clicks the button

```
 $(".header-menu-container").hide().fadeIn(400);
```

I found that it doesn't load fast enough the first time I click the dropDown button,, I thought the problem is with hiding the list twice so I tried

```
var navBtnClicked = false; 
   $(".nav-btn").on('click',function(){
   navBtnClicked = true ;
   if(navBtnClicked){
      $(".header-menu-container").hide().fadeIn(400);
   }
   else
   {
   $(".header-menu-container").fadeIn(400);
   }   })
```

but the problem still remain ... is there a solution or an alternative way to that ?

Comment: do u want it to take time(400ms) to fadeIn? If not then just use `.fadeIn()`

Comment: yea I want it 400ms but the second time the button is clicked it fadesIn  faster so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: also you can't close the menu in your example, it seems broken

Comment: It shouldn't be any faster. It appears like slow at first because you don't have anything and then the menu fades in. Seems to me as an illusion. You can set a lower value for first fade in. See this - https://jsfiddle.net/kmm9pjrv/2/

Comment: oh I just didn't make it close yet , it's not broken :D

Comment: it appears more here http://responsivepx.com/?https%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io%2F7asobate%2Fpen%2FbpjVmd#520x1606

Comment: ok I was just wondering if I was slowing it down or if there was a better solution .. thanks for the answers!